# "Proceed to interview" vs "Proceed to an interview"

Tags: grammar

Which of the two is correct or are both of them correct?

I would like to "proceed to interview" vs. 
I would like to "proceed to an interview"

Is there a difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct. One is a verb and the other a noun.

We proceeded to an interview of the candidate. [suggests one moved (walked) to a place where an interview would be conducted]

We proceeded [began to] to interview [suggests we then interviewed the candidate after doing something else.